# Parallelization of image processing programs on large image set

Tags: bash, image-processing, parallel-processing, scientific-computing

I currently have a very large directory containing over 9000 folders with each holding jpeg images in them (average of 40 per folder).

My program takes an input folder of images and outputs the feature vector of the images in that folder to text files:

```
./process_image images/ output/
```

I also have a script with usage as the following:

```
./script.sh dirlist.txt images/ output/ 1
```

The first input dirlist.txt contains the folder names inside the input directory
The 2nd and 3rd inputs are the base directory for inputs and outputs.
The 4th argument is the index for which entry in the dirlist I want to access

The above example would call, assuming that imageset1 was at index 1 in dirlist.txt:

```
./process_image images/imageset1/ output/imageset1/
```

If I were to do this sequentially, it would take me days to process all 9000 folders. What is the best method for parallelization in this case? Should I write a script that separates the 9000 folders into blocks and runs the script separately, each running a certain range of indexes? Also, how do I determine how many programs I can run, given that one executable can range from 100 MB to 1GB in RAM? I have 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: What is the bottleneck?  io or cpu or memory bandwidth?  What does C++ have to do with this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the problem, and what my bottleneck is. The program is written in C++.

Comment: I just tried processing 10 folders at the same time, and my CPU usage is around 90%. Is it safe to say that my bottleneck is the CPU? I'm running on an i7-3770

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I regularly process 65,000+ images per day and I just about always use GNU Parallel - see [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). I wouldn't bother parallelising C code!

It allows you to specify how many jobs to run in parallel, or just use the default of one job per CPU core. It is pretty simple to use. All you would do is change your `script.sh` so that rather than starting the jobs, it just echoes *all* the commands it would have started, one per line, to `stdout` and then you pipe that into `parallel`, like this

```
script.sh | parallel
```

You can add flags like `-j 8` to run 8 jobs in parallel, or `-k` to keep the output order if that is relevant.

```
script.sh | parallel -j 8 -k
```

Likewise, if you are concerned about memory usage, you can tell `parallel` to only start new jobs when the system has at least 1GB of free memory:

```
script.sh | parallel --memfree 1G
```

You can also add a list of other machines and it will distribute the jobs across them for you :-)

Here is a tiny example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh

for i in {0..99}; do
   echo "echo Start job $i; sleep 5; echo End job $i"
done
```

Then

```
script.sh | parallel
```

and the 500 seconds of work gets done in 70 seconds on my 8-core machine, or 21 seconds if I use `parallel -j 25`.

Comment: The `--noswap` is known to be hrmmm.... non-optimal. Try the new `--memfree 1G` instead.

Comment: @OleTange Thank you, as usual, for your invaluable inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Very useful stuff. Unfortunately, I'm on Windows right now, and was not quite able to get GNU Parallel working. I think I found xargs to be an alternative. Do you happen to know the syntax to perform the same as "script.sh | parallel -j 8" using xargs?

Comment: I tried "script.sh | xargs -n8 -P8", but it seems to be spawning only 1 at the time. When I add & at the end of the script line i want executed, it then spawns way more than 8.

Comment: "echo {0..100} | xargs -n 1 -P 8 ./script.sh" Did the job, though I'm not sure how this differs to GNU parallel

Comment: I'm glad you found success with `xargs` - it would be hard to deduce you are on Windows when you use things like `script.sh` :-). You could maybe consider running a live Linux distro that runs from CD without installation to your hard drive... e.g. Knoppix.

Comment: I have tested GNU Parallel under Cygwin, and all basic functionality works - though probably not --memfree.

Answer (score 0):

1. **bottleneck**

   CPU usage is not a valid bottleneck sign the best way to decide what is the bottleneck is by measurements. When you hit the bottleneck then the CPU usage usually hit 100% or near but that only means that some bottleneck is reached.

   If the bottleneck is from IO then the CPU usage can be low ... to measure CPU/MEM you need to use different CPU and transfer speeds so change setting in BIOS to see if times change rapidly. This will not always help to determine the source in that case you have to measure runtime of parts of your program and see what is slow.

   Then determine it yourself based on what that part of code does there are also profiling tools out there which do some of this automatically
2. **parallelization**

   you can parallelize only thread safe parts of the code so if you use non-thread safe libs then those parts cant be parallelized. Also if you have dependent parts of code to each other then parallelization is not too gaining without knowing more about the processing background of your task is hard to say

   so easiest and safest way is process folder per thread
3. **number of threads**

   I usually use as many threads as I have CPU's available this number is obtainable (on windows) from system affinity. On timing demanding apps I use 1st CPU as main code and only the rest as threads. In your case using too many threads will cause IO to be in conflicts with other threads (unless you have RAM/SSD drive)
4. **scheduling**

   for similar task duration just divide tasks to threads evenly for very different tasks runtimes use some sort of scheduling for example create que of tasks and then periodicaly check all threads if they are busy. Find first free thread and fetch task from que to it.

   **Do not forget to add Sleep() to this loop** if all tasks are done then stop all the threads and exit

Comment: `Sleep` ? You've got to be kidding. It's far easier for an idle thread to pick up work itself. That's instant, and removes the need for a main loop that's almost-always sleeping and generally half a nap late when something must be done.

Comment: @MSalters (+1)I agree self employing threads are faster but need far more experience to write them right (in thread safe manner) for longer jobs like few seconds per folder and main loop Sleep around OS scheduling granularity is the waste not that significant (but that needs to be measured on specific implementation to be sure)

Comment: Thread safety if quite trivial: just slap a mutex on the list of open tasks. Reading and processing a single image is sufficiently complex that the mutex will not cause significant contention. (If contention _is_ a problem, break up the task list in N sublists protected by N mutexes )